# How might one find students interested in working on research projects remotely?

Tags: supervision

Often graduate students work with professors within their local University on research projects. However, I am aware of a few institutions that allow (or actually require) students to seek outside collaborations for research projects (e.g. capstone projects). Given that many people are still working remotely, this seems like a good time to capitalize on remote collaborations (although I understand some may be wary of such relationships).

Is anyone aware of such opportunities for collaboration? Perhaps there is a forum / board or other somewhere that connects students to research opportunities?

Comment: Frankly this is going to be very different for graduate students vs. undergrads, which one are you searching for? Are you attempting to recruit undergrads from another institution?

Comment: Thanks @AzorAhai-him- for this point. I've edited to include just graduate students in the text - I only meant to ask about graduate students, although I'd be interested to hear about opportunities for either.

Comment: Can't you just post a job advert in the usual place for your field? In physics we use AAS Jobs, mathjobs, inspire-hep jobs etc. I imagine most fields have similar websites.